# FileReader onload only works the second time around in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm working on in-browser image processing with HTML5 and have a weird issue in Firefox with the onload event handler for the File API FileReader class (which works properly on chrome): the file is only processed properly the second time it's selected in the form.

Any idea how I can get Firefox to process this event the first time around?

Ps: I'm using Linux, maybe that's relevant?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ow126vah/

Code:

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var imageType = /image.*/;

  if (file.type.match(imageType)) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {

      var ctx = fileDisplayArea.getContext("2d");

      // create a new image from user selected file
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = reader.result;

      // set canvas size to image size
      fileDisplayArea.width = img.width;
      fileDisplayArea.height = img.height;

      // scale and draw image with offset
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    alert("File not supported!");
  }
})
```

```html
<div>Select an image file:
  <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
<canvas id="fileDisplayArea"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not with FileReader. The load handler gets executed every time. The problem seems to be with the timing of accessing the image. Wait until it is loaded:

```
// create a new image from user selected file
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  // set canvas size to image size
  fileDisplayArea.width = img.width;
  fileDisplayArea.height = img.height;

  // scale and draw image with offset
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = reader.result;
```

I assume it works the second time because the image is cached one way or the other.

Comment: Took a moment to understand what you meant, but that works. Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/ow126vah/3/

Comment: Wow, it's really obvious when you say it and it works. Do you know why the FF works differently in this case? It sure makes sense to use img.onload in any browser, but it's not needed in any other browser then FF. Do they automatically wait until the image is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

for Firefox we need to wait :

```
//ecouteur sur le chargement du reader
reader.onload = function(e) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;

    //Attendre fin du chargement de l'image...
    setTimeout(function(){ my_action_to_modify_image;}, 500);//Increase this value if doesn't work
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's only a semi good solution. Waiting for img.onload as Felix suggested is better, because you are basically guessing how long it takes to load the image.